# Assign line number to one of the fields based on the no. of fields in each row

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I need to manipulate one of my data files using awk command like this. How can I accomplish this using awk? Any inputs would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
1) Get the no. of fields for each row.
   (a) If the count_of_fields = 'x' then assign a value to nth field in each row.
```

***Input*** :-

```
1,x,A,B
2,A,B,C
3,x,C,D
4,D,E,F,G
5,x,E,F
```

**

***Output***

** :-

```
1,1,A,B
2,A,B,C
3,3,C,D
4,D,E,F,G
5,5,E,F

x- is the 2nd column where I would like to assign NR when NF=4
n - This is the 2nd column.
```

Comment: Please make the example clearer, what are `x` and `n` in the the input ? Also what have you tried up to now ?

Comment: THINK about the sample input/output you provided. You seem to have a requirement to ONLY do something when a field is x and NF is 4 so why would you only post sample input where every time a field is x NF **is always** 4? As written someone could write a solution that completely ignores your requirement to only change x when NF is 4 and test it against your posted sample input and it would produce your expected output. Also you **always** have x in the field you WANT changed so we could ignore that requirement too. That's a terrible example, not even close to covering your use cases!

Comment: For example, I could post a solution that's just `awk '{sub(/x/,NR)}1' file` and when run against your posted sample input it would produce your posted expected output. Its completely the wrong solution of course so what value did your sample input/output add? None. It's always easy to make changes you want and much harder to avoid changing things you don't want changed so when creating sample input/output really put some effort into coming up with the cases you think will be hard to get right, at least include cases that cover your most basic requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear.
In awk, the built-in variables `NF` and `NR` denote the number of fields in each line and the record/line number, respectively.

To get the desired output from the given input, I would do the following:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$2=="x"{$2=NR}1' test.txt
```

This replaces each `x` in the second column by the line number:

```
1,1,A,B
2,A,B,C
3,3,C,D
4,D,E,F,G
5,5,E,F
```

**Update:** If you want to replace the 2nd column's content by NR if the number of fields equals 4:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}NF==4{$2=NR}1' test.txt
```

Output:

```
1,1,A,B
2,2,B,C
3,3,C,D
4,D,E,F,G
5,5,E,F
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
awk -v count=4 -v ndx=2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } NF==count { $ndx = NR } 1' file
```

If the 2nd field should only be replaced if its original value is `x` (to be consistent with your sample output):

```
awk -v count=4 -v ndx=2 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } NF==count && $ndx=="x" { $ndx = NR } 1' file
```

- `-v count=4 -v ndx=2`

  passes the desired field count as `awk` variable `count` to the `awk` script, and the index of the target field as variable `ndx`.
- `BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }`

  executed only *once*, before the rest of the script, sets both the *input* field separator (`FS`) and the *output* field separator to `,` so that `awk` breaks the input into fields by commas, and also uses commas as separators when rebuilding the line after changing a field value. <sup>Thanks, [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton).</sup>
- `NF==count`

  is a pattern that tests the field count (`NF`) against the `count` variable and executes the following action (`{...}`) only if the values are equal.
- `{ $ndx = NR }`

  assigns the current (1-based) row index (`NR`) to the field with index `ndx`, effectively rebuilding the input line with the new field value.
- `1`

  is a common shorthand to simply *print* the (potentially modified) input line. (`1` is effectively equivalent to `{ print }`: pattern `1` invariably evaluates to true, and since it has no associated action, the default action kicks in, which is to simply print the line.)